# How to combine several data files into one big data file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have several data file like `file1.dat`, `file2.dat` and so on. I want to combine them all in one big data file so that content of big data file should look like

```
content1

content2

.

.


contentN
```

I know that

```
cat file1.dat file2.dat .... >> bigfile.dat
```

will do the job but **I don't want to type all file names**.  Is there any command which will do it?

Comment: If you don't want to type all of the file names, is there instead some sort of pattern common to all of them that you could use to recognize them?

Answer (score 2):

If all of your input files indeed match the pattern `file`, followed
by some number, followed by `.dat`, then this would concatenate all of
them together into `bigfile.dat`:

```
cat file*.dat >bigfile.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on exactly how many files there are, and the naming convention used, but given your example:

```
cat file[0-9].dat
content1
content2
```

The files (individually):

```
cat file1.dat 
content1
cat file2.dat 
content2
```

Answer (score 1):

So I suppose they are not named like in your example, otherwise you could simply do

```
cat file*.dat > bigfile.dat
```

So you need some scheme to find all your files, probably with `find`. For eample, if you want to combine all files with `.dat`:

```
find /your/search/dir -name "*.dat" -exec cat {} \; >> bigfile.dat
```

Just make sure, you don't create `bigfile.dat` in your search directory or it will be found by `find` as well, which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for (( i=1; i<=N; i++ )); do cat file"$i".dat; done > bigfile.dat
```